# Using strtotime() PHP and revert back trough gmdate() is not returning same date

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a string `$StartDate = "2015-09-23"` (should be like yyyy-mm-dd).
Than I make `$UdtStart=  strtotime($StartDate)` that returns 1442980800;
Well if I go to this [link](http://www.unixtimestamp.org/1442980800) it return back "Wed, 23 Sep 2015 04:00:00 +0000".
First, why do we have 04:00:00 added?

Than, if I do this $back=gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", ($UdtStart)); I will have "2015-09-26 04:00:00".

What am I missing?

```
$UdtStart=  strtotime($StartDate);
$back=gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", ($UdtStart));
```

Comment: Because that date is UTC. You probably want `date()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Wed, 23 Sep 2015 04:00:00 +0000
```

Note that `+0000` on the end, that means the time is UTC. As per the [PHP strtotime() doco](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter.

The `gmdate` is for Greenwich Mean Time (and really should be called something like `utcdate` nowadays), so you're asking for the data in a different foramt from what you gave it.

I'd be willing to bet money that you're in a timezone four hours removed from UTC, which is why you're seeing that.

If you want *local* time, use `date()` rather than `gmdate()`. The [`gmdate` doco](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) states:

> Identical to the `date()` function except that the time returned is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).